# Can I get Boost-Python to fill out the __dict__ member for my wrapped classes

Tags: python, c++, json, boost, boost-python

I'm wrapping a bunch of C++ classes with Boost-Python and I want to be able to serialize the python version of these classes to JSON using `json.dumps`. I expected to be able to use the `__dict__` attribute of the wrapped classes to do that, but unfortunately `__dict__ == {}` in all of my wrapped classes.

Is there a parameter to the `class_` template or something to let Boost-Python know that I want all of my `.def_readwrite`, `.add_property`, etc entries to also be added to `__dict__`?

Comment: Do your classes have a `.__getstate__()` method?  Because that's how `pickle` works with Boost Python.  If so, can you try JSON dumping the result of that method?

Comment: Just checked, no `__getstate__`